# Why doesn't my function return a float?

Tags: c++, arrays

I've made a program for finding the average of a one dimensional array. It sort of works but my problem is the float subprogram doesn't return float in main.

```
void vnesi_niza(int n, int a[50])
{
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout << "a[" << i << "]=";
        cin > >a[i];
    }
}

float sreden_uspeh(int n, int a[50])
{
    int sum=0;
    float as;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        sum+=a[i];
        as=sum/n;
    }
    return as;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    int niza[50];
    cout << "input the number of elements" << endl;
    cout << "n=";
    cin >> n;
    vnesi_niza(n,niza);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "the average is " << endl;
    cout << sreden_uspeh(n,niza); //sreden_uspeh means average
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The answers below are okay. You should also consider moving the division outside of the for loop. You don't need this `as` value. You could just `return static_cast<float>(sum)/n;` at the end of your loop.

Comment: Your function *does* return a `float`. But `floats` can hold integer values (an `int` is a perfectly valid `float`) and what you are calculating and returning is a `int`.

Answer (score 3):

Since the sum of the grades is of type `int` the division operation will be the integer division, that is it will floor down to the previous closest integer. So you should instead do a decimal division like this: `as = (1.0 * sum) / n`.

Note: You don't need to calculate the average value each time in the loop, it is enough to do it once out of the loop where you will return it.

Comment: `as = (1.0 * sum) / n;` reminds me about my math prof. (who surely made his code in Fortran). `as = (float)sum / n;` would do as well. ;-) Btw. `1.0` is a `double` constant - `1.0f` the `float` companion of it. (Sorry for the nitpicking.)

Answer (score 2):

The line `as=sum/n` performs integer division, then assigns `as` equal to the result, so the `sreden_uspeh` function returns the average of the input array truncated (rounded down) to an integer.

If you declare the variable `sum` as `float sum = 0` (instead of as `int sum = 0`) then `n` will be cast to a float and floating point division will happen with `as=sum/n`, as per [conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic).

Or, you can just cast the first operand to a float when you do the division, `as=(float)sum/n`.

Also you are assigning `as` but not using it each iteration of the loop, which is inefficient.  In fact you can just write

```
float sreden_uspeh(int n, int a[50])
{
    int sum=0;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        sum+=a[i];
    }
    return (float)sum/n;
}
```

Also be aware `int a[50]` is decayed to the pointer type `int *a`; the full array is not passed to `sreden_uspeh`.

Also, it is common when you are performing integer division to also take the modulus (using the `%` operator) since taking both the integer quotient and modulus you don't lose any info.

Answer (score 0):

You made a small mistake. The type of `sum` is `int` it should be `float`.

```
float sreden_uspeh(int n, int a[50])
{
    float sum=0;
    float as;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        sum+=a[i];
        as=sum/n;
    }
    return as;
}
```

One more mistake in statement `cin > >a[i];` .

Comment: I tried it, it works. But why should it be a float? Isn't only the return value supposed to be a float, i mean when you divide an int you can still get a float.

Comment: @1nightstamp: No. in C/C++ if yo divide an integer by another integer, the result again is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

when you put int/int the answer gets calculated in int . after wards it get transformed to float,,  so you have to make it float/int